# When we typecast the int to double does the actual address where int is stored is get changed?

Tags: c, casting

I want to know that when we typecast the int to double does the actual result where int is stored is get changed or increased? because int is of 4 bytes(lets assume) and when we it get typecast to double which is of 8 bytes(assumption) then does the size also increased now to store the value of double?
And please go easy on me if it is a stupid question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Casting doesn't affect the variable and the corresponding memory. It's just and indication for the compiler how to interpret the bits the reside at the given location.

In Marcus'es example:

```
int i = 12;
double d = (double)i;
```

`d` is a new variable in a completely new location. The original value, `i`, is not affected. However, if you start playing with pointers then you have to be careful:

```
int i = 12;
double *p = &i;
```

Now, if `double` is 8 bytes wide then note that by using `p` you/compiler assume that it points to a memory location that has 8 bytes of memory allocated for the variable that it's pointing to. This is however not true, because in fact it's pointing to `i`, which is only 4 bytes wide (assume that `int` is 4 bytes wide).

**EDIT**

This is a (relatively) recent edit motivated by OPs request for clarification in the comments. The OP wants to know:

> what happens to the memory address of sum when it get typecast does
>   now typecasted value of sum stored somewhere else in the memory

and here's the code:

```
 int sum = 17, count = 5; 
 double mean; 
 mean = (double) sum / count;
```

There's actually quite a lot going in the above three lines of code. However, the important thing here is that the variable `sum` is not being modified at all. It's only being used as an argument in addition. For the sake of adding two variables you only need the corresponding values. Before adding, the compiler will most likely copy the two variables into registers. Because you're casting to a double, the compiler will very likely store the value of `sum` in a 64 bit wide register (assume that double is 64 bit wide) and that's it. However, bear in mind that this is implementation specific and will vary from one compiler to another. It's not something that's specified by the C standard.

At this point, if you want to understand more you're best of compiling to Assembly and trying to understand that. Hope this helps!

Comment: but i donot understand from where that extra memory comes which is used to store the typecast result as if we are going to typecast int into double it may be takes more bits than int.

Comment: @PrinceVijayPratap In a lot of practical cases it's managed internally by the compiler. It would be easier if you point to a line of code that's confusing.

Comment: It will either be allocated on the run time dynamic memory, or be pre-allocated by the compiler, if it can deduct that it will need that memory in any case.

Comment: @PrinceVijayPratap Note that in the first example I defined a new variable, `d`. That variable sits in a completely different memory location from `i`, and is most likely allocated on the stack.

Comment: instead of d can we use same variable i? then does it get allocated to a new memory space?

Comment: @PrinceVijayPratap That would qualify as re-declaration with conflicting types, which is illegal. In any scope (i.e. between curly braces: `{}`)  once you declare `i` as `int` it has stay as `int`.

Comment: @PrinceVijayPratap: To be blunt,I'd like to ask you why you care about the memory location of your variable so much.If you want something written to the space that belongs to a variable of a different type,get the address of that variable with the `&` prefix operator,cast the resulting `double *` to an `char *` (strictly speaking,that's not valid C, but works on every compiler) and copy over whatever you want byte-wise.In general, you *just let the compiler do its job and write and use variables as variables*. If you need one memory object to be interpreted as two different types, use `union`!

Comment: @banach-space                                                                                                        int sum = 17, count = 5;
double mean;                                                                                             mean = (double) sum / count;
please tell me now what happens to the memory address of sum when it get typecast does now typecasted value of sum stored somewhere else in the memory

Comment: @PrinceVijayPratap Please check my last edit. It was too long for a comment. And what you asked about is not obvious. Hope this answers your question now?

Answer (score 2):

That is the same question as "in `a = b + c * d;` where is the intermediate result of `c * d` stored?".

Simple answer: in a temporary variable manged by the compiler. This will most likely be a register. The language standard does not define this - why should it actually?

The typecast is actually similar to `-b` (b negated). This would also have to be stored somewhere prior to being used.

Note that the original value is not modified and the receiving variable has to be of the proper type anyway (that is one reason why you cannot typecast the receiving variable).

The int to double/float conversion is done by the compiler implicitly, so there is no need for an explicit cast - and it should not be used in such cases, as it will hide problem arising by later changes to the types.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know that when we typecast the int to double does the actual result where int is stored is get changed or increased?

Since int and double in C are two distinct types, yes, casting an int to a double cannot happen in the same place where the int was -- even if these two types had the same size.

To illustrate: if casting overwrote the original variable, what would the effects of

```
int i = 12;
double d = (double)i;
int i2; 
i2 = i + i;
```

be?

EDIT: @Dani added that

> The double can occupy the same address if the int is no longer used.

Yes, compilers can check whether a variable will/could be accessed at a later point and can do operations in-place if that helps; however that's not the case here:

1. in general, you must assume the address will be different
2. in this case, the types don't even have the same size
3. in my example, `i` is accessed later on, and
4. in reality, that's not likely to be a good idea -- depending on what's about to happen to the double after casting on a modern CPU is that it will most likely be written into a special register dedicated to floating point processing, which will not be the one in which the `int` was.

Comment: why the downvotes? I have the same answer as banach-space; that answer even cites me!

Comment: The double can occupy the same address if the int is no longer used.

Comment: @Dani, that's a special case that can only apply if the integer is really no longer used (yes, compilers are smart and can notice that), and even more important here, if the size constraints allow. For all machines that I would know of, that's not the case for `double` and `int`.

Answer (score 0):

when we typecast the `int` to `double` does the actual result where int is stored is get changed or increased?

No, Type casting is only a way to convert a variable from one data type to another data type.

when we do

```
int i = 10;
double d = (double)i;
```

actually, we are doing  the `arithmetic promotion`. Since `double` is of `8 Byte` and `int` is of `4 Byte`. Hence, there would be no loss. But vice-versa is not true.

Type conversions can be implicit which is performed by the compiler automatically, or it can be specified explicitly through the use of the cast operator.

Usual Arithmetic Conversion are performed using following hierarchy.

[image: Usual Arithmetic Conversion]

Answer (score 0):

The result of the cast might not get stored anywhere; in fact, it might never be computed at all!

If I have a program fragment

```
int i = 42;
double j;
j = 1.0 + (double) i;
```

the program only has to behave *as if* the conversion happened and then the result was added to `1.0`, but so long as the end result is correct, the program is allowed to produce that result in any way it wants; it doesn't even have to *resemble* the code you've written.

e.g. on a machine with a suitable "add integer an floating point number" instruction, the compiler may opt to give you a program that uses that instruction, rather than performing a conversion followed by an addition.